# How to separate the character in binary form and checksum them c#

Tags: c#, return, byte, xor, crc

```
ff03c1 3d
```

how to xor this string and get checksum `3d` ?

the scenario is:

i get string like `ff03c13d`. (there are other models with longer lengths).
and i should check crc in hex;

like this:

`ff` xor `03` xor `c1` and if result equal the last two characters or the last byte (like `3d`) return True.

thanks for your help

Comment: Could you please clarify what you have problem with and also what exactly this assignment calls for - sounds like you asked to perform XOR on textual representation of bytes in Hex... Can you at least use tables to simply it or you need to convert each character to bits and Xor manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq, `Where`, `Select`, `Aggregate`, `ToString`

```
var hex = "ff03c1";
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                       .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                       .Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                       .Aggregate((i, i1) => i ^ i1)
                       .ToString("X");

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pimC7u)

**Method**

```
public static bool Check(string hex)
{
   return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length-2)
                    .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                    .Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                    .Aggregate((i, i1) => i ^ i1)
                    .ToString("x") == hex.Substring(hex.Length-2);
}
```

**Usage**

```
var hex = "ff03c13d";

Console.WriteLine(Check(hex));
```

**Output**

```
True
```

Comment: Thankful. Very clean

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the vaues using [int.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Int32.Parse);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) with [NumberStyles.HexNumber](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberstyles?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Globalization.NumberStyles);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) to extract the values from the string, `XOR` the parts the needs `XOR`ing (each `Hex` value in `string.Length -2`) and compare with the `CRC` represented by the last 2 `Hex` symbols in the string.

Something like this:

Using the provided string:

```
bool isValid = CRC("ff03c13d");
```

```
private bool CRC(string input)
{
    if (input.Length % 2 != 0) throw new InvalidOperationException(input);

    int result = -1;
    if (int.TryParse(input.Substring(input.Length - 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber, null, out int CRC)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length - 2; i += 2) 
        {
            if (int.TryParse(input.Substring(i, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber, null, out int value)) { 
                result ^= value;
            } else { throw new InvalidDataException(input); }
        }
    }
    else { throw new InvalidDataException(input); }
    return result == CRC;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below function can make XOR of your hex string

```
public static string GetXOR(string input)
{
    if (input.Length % 2 == 0)
    {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i = i + 2)
        {
            string hex = input.Substring(i, 2);
            int hexInt = Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16);
            result ^= hexInt;
        }

        return result.ToString("X");
    }
    return "Wrong Input";
}
```

And you can use it like

```
string input = "ff03c1";
string ouput = GetXOR(input);

Console.WriteLine(ouput);
Console.ReadLine();
```

**Output:**

[image]